# jQuery Ajax beforesend, success and error with axios

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, axios

I have a contact form on a static web page that I'm sending via formspree.
I'm trying to implement ajax submit to avoid redirecting the page.

I've found this [gist](https://gist.github.com/jannecederberg/785c1dc78e882b6bf85a5e77b31b0678#file-formspree-js) that does it in jQuery.

**jQuery**

```
var $contactForm = $('#contact-form');

$contactForm.submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $submit = $('input:submit', $contactForm);
    var defaultSubmitText = $submit.val();

    $.ajax({
        url: '//formspree.io/your@email.com',
        method: 'POST',
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function() {
            $submit.attr('disabled', true).val('Sending message…');
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $submit.val('Message sent!');
            setTimeout(function() {
                $submit.attr('disabled', false).val(defaultSubmitText);
            }, 5000);
        },
        error: function(err) {
            $submit.val('Oops, there was an error.');
            setTimeout(function() {
                $submit.attr('disabled', false).val(defaultSubmitText);
            }, 5000);
        }
    });
});
```

I would like to use only native javascript, so far this is how I've "translated it"

**Native JS**

```
const form = document.querySelector('form');

form.addEventListener("submit", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    const $submit = form.querySelector('.contact__submit');
    const defaultSubmitText = $submit.innerHTML;

    axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'https://formspree.io/your@email.com',
        data: serialize(form)
        // https://plainjs.com/javascript/ajax/serialize-form-data-into-a-query-string-45/
    })
        .then(function(response) {
            console.log('SENT!!', response.data);
        })
        .catch(function(){
            console.log('ERROR!!');
        });
    //https://github.com/stefanpenner/es6-promise
});
```

How can i "translate" `beforeSend`, to let the user know that the message is sending ?

Comment: Well, your `beforeSend` does not change the xhr object, so you can do your thing before calling `axios`.

Comment: what if our `beforeSend` change `xhr` object?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but let me drop how I was able to get mine to work. I had the same issue when trying to re-write my jQuery code in vanilla JS, what I did was use [interceptors](https://axios-http.com/docs/interceptors).

Using your example code

```
const form = document.querySelector('form');

form.addEventListener("submit", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    const $submit = form.querySelector('.contact__submit');
    const defaultSubmitText = $submit.innerHTML;

    // Axios BeforeSend equivalent
    axios.interceptors.request.use( config => {
       // Write whatever logic you want to run beforeSend here
        $submit.attr('disabled', true).val('Sending message…');

        return config; // very Important to add this, else Axios will cancel itself
    });

    axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'https://formspree.io/your@email.com',
        data: serialize(form)
        // https://plainjs.com/javascript/ajax/serialize-form-data-into-a-query-string-45/
    })
    .then(function(response) {
        console.log('SENT!!', response.data);
    })
    .catch(function(){
        console.log('ERROR!!');
    });
    //https://github.com/stefanpenner/es6-promise
});
```

You as well have the option to do something like `BeforeReceive` (i.e do something before the response is returned):

```
axios.interceptors.response.use( config => {
   // Write whatever logic you want to run beforeReceieve here
    return config;
});
```